# 'SqlConnection' is not declared error for aspx net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am fairly new to this Aspx.Net.  I am trying to connect to a remote SQL Server and below is the connection string I am trying on IIS server.

SQL Server version is 2012

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Database=DB;Server=server.name;Uid=user.name;Pwd=pass");
connection.Open();

MySqlCommand command =  connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select * from dbo.TableName";
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
  //reader.GetString(0)
  //reader["column_name"].ToString()
}

reader.Close();
```

Below is the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Compilation Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'SqlConnection' is not declared.

Appreciate any help, please keep in mind this is my first tries out on aspx. Yes, I tried searching online but can't seem to find a resolution.

Comment: I don't see any references to `SqlConnection` in your code, which appears to be what the exception is referring to, but one thing I do notice is that you mention that you are connecting to *Microsoft SQL Server*, but you are using the libraries used to connect to *MySql* databases.

Comment: You're using MySQL, not MSSQL. Change this :))

Comment: @Diado I changed from MySQL to MSSQL but still the same error
@ Tomato32 Done but same

Comment: Seems you have not provided the current code you are using and having the issue, the error message says`Name 'SqlConnection' is not declared.` but i don't see you used `SqlConnection` anywhere.

Comment: I am learning aspx and a beginner so trying to connect to db first.

Thats all is my code

@Md.SumanKabir can you correct or add what is wrong?

Comment: The error you are getting is IMPOSSIBLE from the code posted. SqlConnection is not in your code anywhere. And using a MySQL connection object to connect to sql server isn't going to work out too well for you.

Comment: @X10nD Follow my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to use SQL Server in C#, try follow below technique:

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Server=server.name;Database=DB;User Id=userid;Password=yourpass;");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.TableName", sqlConn);
sqlConn.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    //reader.GetString(0)
    //reader["column_name"].ToString()
}

reader.Close();
sqlConn.Close();
```

Comment: Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'SqlConnection' is not declared.


Here you go, back to square one

Comment: Have you added the related namespace `using System.Data.SqlClient;` ?

Comment: Help on that pls?

Comment: Did you use my code? If yes, which line is pointing when you clicked the error? Please provide better information to get better help, you know that. I am saying because variable `SqlConnection` is not used in my code, so no reason to get this error.

Comment: Line 8:  SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Server=

Comment: It's confusing, can you attach a screenshot of code just when it is showing the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177294/discussion-between-md-suman-kabir-and-x10nd).